# r code to convert 'missing' character to 0

Tags: r, type-conversion, dataset

I know only basics in R and was trying to learn deeper, please help me with this

#### this is how my data looks

```
Beach.Name          Water.Temperature Turbidity Wave.Height Wave.Period
7   Calumet Beach              16.3      1.28       0.162           4
72        missing           missing   missing     missing     missing
18  Calumet Beach                17      1.82       0.194           4
78        missing           missing   missing     missing     missing
24 Montrose Beach              14.5      6.88       0.345           4
41  Calumet Beach              15.9      1.74       0.148           4
```

#### expected out put is

```
   Beach.Name        Water.Temperature Turbidity Wave.Height Wave.Period
7   Calumet Beach              16.3      1.28       0.162           4
72        missing                 0         0           0           0
18  Calumet Beach                17      1.82       0.194           4
78        missing                 0         0           0           0
24 Montrose Beach              14.5      6.88       0.345           4
41  Calumet Beach              15.9      1.74       0.148           4
```

in prior to this the way I placed missing vales at random with the below code , now I require to perform 1-NN on that data , but couldn't cause of non -numeric arguments existence

```
>data5=data5 %>% select(1:5) 
>df.new5 <- data10[-sample(NROW(data10), NROW(data10)*(1 - 0.05),),]<-'missing'
>df.new5 <- data10[sample(NROW(data10), NROW(data10)*(1 - 0.05),),]
```

Comment: Are you sure you want 0 and not `NA`? `NA` will allow you to do all the calculations without introducing fake data. If that's agreeable, just change the class of each column to numeric, and the "missing" will be coerced into `NA`.

Answer (score 0):

If your columns are factors, change them to characters first, then replace all the `"missing"` values with 0, use `type.convert` to convert the class.

```
df[] <- lapply(df, as.character)
df[-1][df[-1] == "missing"] <- 0
df <- type.convert(df)
df

#      Beach.Name Water.Temperature Turbidity Wave.Height Wave.Period
#7   CalumetBeach              16.3      1.28       0.162           4
#72       missing               0.0      0.00       0.000           0
#18  CalumetBeach              17.0      1.82       0.194           4
#78       missing               0.0      0.00       0.000           0
#24 MontroseBeach              14.5      6.88       0.345           4
#41  CalumetBeach              15.9      1.74       0.148           4
```

---

However, as mentioned by @iod and @dww it's probably better to keep data with `NA` instead of 0 which would be useful for doing further calculations. For example you can see the difference in them by taking  `mean`.

With 0's

```
sapply(df[-1], mean, na.rm = TRUE)
#Water.Temperature         Turbidity       Wave.Height       Wave.Period 
#            10.62              1.95              0.14              2.67
```

With `NA`s

```
df[-1] <- lapply(df[-1], function(x) as.numeric(as.character(x)))
sapply(df[-1], mean, na.rm = TRUE)

#Water.Temperature         Turbidity       Wave.Height       Wave.Period 
#            15.93              2.93              0.21              4.00
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(Beach.Name = structure(c(1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L
), .Label = c("CalumetBeach", "missing", "MontroseBeach"), class = "factor"), 
Water.Temperature = structure(c(3L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("14.5", 
"15.9", "16.3", "17", "missing"), class = "factor"), Turbidity = structure(c(1L, 
5L, 3L, 5L, 4L, 2L), .Label = c("1.28", "1.74", "1.82", "6.88", 
"missing"), class = "factor"), Wave.Height = structure(c(2L, 
5L, 3L, 5L, 4L, 1L), .Label = c("0.148", "0.162", "0.194", 
"0.345", "missing"), class = "factor"), Wave.Period = structure(c(1L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("4", "missing"), 
class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", 
row.names = c("7", "72", "18", "78", "24", "41"))
```

Comment: @SmruthiDabbiru Can you elaborate `could'nt make it` ?  What didn't work ?

Comment: did you run `df[] <- lapply(df, as.character)` first ?

Comment: yeah I did , maybe I did some thing wrong will do it again